# Our own web Services vs IoT`s APIs to have highest security

Tags: security, networking, firewall, firebase-security, iot

I have two scenarios for implementing IoT devices and I want to know which one has most security? Because I am a programmer and I have bit knowledge on network issues

***Main Goal*** is to implement IoT devices and have modification and configuration from outside of local network. Assume we have IoT device in smart house and I want to change its configuration from outside of house by changing some parameters.

NOW:

***First Scenario:*** 
On the below picture indicates with red color on the left.

Writing our own web services and make it accessible by setting up "static ip" and and using "Port Forwarding" + SSH in order to have high secure connection.

In this story, user write static ip on address bar from outside of smart house and connect to web services and can have modification

now my question is if this way can harmful for our firewall and network?
If this way open firewall port permanantly?
If all users can send request so do we have attackers that can attack other devices or not?

We can have our authentication to have more safty.

***Second Scenario:*** 
On the below picture indicates with blue color on the right.

In this scenario we are using APIs from IoT company instead of writing our own services and user send request to IoT Company and on the our smart house we have gateway from IoT company which send request for instance per 1 second to check if ther is any on IoT company server or not and if there is any so make a modification.

Because in this scenario Iot Company might to use DHCP IP instead of static ip , is it possible to have some hurt to fire wall?

Because I am not sure but I think firewall will be opened whenever ther is any request so is it possible that this way is more secure?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If possible, I would suggest not opening any port on the IoT device. This does create a lot of worries as the question suggests.

Instead, would it make sense in your case to have the IoT device poll a web service for instructions? You could use web sockets or long-polling if it's important for the devices to be highly responsive to incoming requests.

Comment: Did you mean that the most secure way is to use our own web service with ip static but instead of using or opening port we should use web sockets or long polling?

Comment: Yes use your own web service, but no I would not recommend using an IP directly. Use a domain name so you can change your DNS settings later. Enable DNSSEC for your domain if you like. As for WS and long polling - these are 2 ways in which you can have the IoT device constantly connected to your web service so that it's highly responsive to requests. The alternative would be periodic polling which is less responsive.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response , as I understood the best way from your idea is :   1. Enable DNSSEC on Domain - instead of port forwarding or opening any port on fire wall -    2. Trigger IoT by WS or Long Pooling due to have connection   3. Using Web Services instead of using IoT Company `s APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Mahsa's description is not detailed enough, so i decided to add some more information... otherwise it would be a *"what tastes better: a pear or an apple?"* discussion.

#### More precise scenarios

The **first scenario (S1)** uses port forwarding. This port can be used by everybody in the internet. Security is based on the software and implementation of that webservice. Which has to be maintained good and updated regulary.

The **Second scenario (S2)** does a polling from a internet-server, maintained by the manufacturer (Philips). The local IoT-gateway initiates a TCP/HTTP-rest-request to the philips-hue server in the internet. The firewall/NAT does not need to be changed at all. *"Open Port whenever we need"* is not 100% correct, it's a NAT-firewall which accepts only packets from request destination of Philips-server (SPI)

**Please read** about how networks, firewall and NAT works in most environments before making assumptions:

- Network: OSI Layers 3,4,7 (and at the moment we talk about IPv4 ;-)
- [Firewall/SPI: Stateful Package Inspection](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_Packet_Inspection)
- [NAT: Port-restricted cone or symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_translation/)

---

#### Questions of safety

What is "safety" in your case? You have to define what you want to protect. In this case it's the local network,so that no intrusion is possible. The detailed questions *"what is more safe?"* are:

**A1)** port-forwarding or **A2)** port-restricted/symmetric NAT and SPI?

**B1)** pattern user ⇒ firewall ⇒ own webservice ⇒ gateway or **B2)** pattern user ⇒ Philips-server **⇐** firewall **⇐** gateway

**C1)** security is based on higher layer 5-7 or **C2)** based on lower layers 3+4

---

#### Side aspects

The picture should tell that the "own web service" can **NOT** directly talk to the IoT-device. It has to talk over the gateway/bridge with the IoT-device.
This means you have to setup a local webserver parallel to the IoT-gateway.

**D)** Costs, effort and the maintennance of such local webservice... is it really needed to have a secure scenario?

#### Please send your answers A-D

and some arguments would be nice. Perhaps you find also some other security issues E,F,G,H... let us know. *Thanks Frank*

Comment: Thank you so much for completing my scenario with valuable information